Evaluating a summation of product
Show that for any integer $k>1$
$$
\sum_{\substack{i_j \in \{0, 1\} \forall j < k, i_k = 0}} \prod_{j = 1}^{k} \left(i_j + (-1)^{i_j} \frac{a+ (j - 1) c - c \sum_{\lambda = 0}^{j - 1} i_\lambda}{a+b + (j - 1) c}\right) = \frac{a}{a+b}
$$
where $a,b,c>0$.
Well, this problem actually came from a probability problem. Although I have solved that problem through other means, I am still troubled by the evaluation of this summation. Here is the original problem:
There are $a$ red balls and $b$ white balls in a box. Each time, a ball is drawn randomly from the box, and then $c+1$ balls of the same color are added back into the box. The task is to show that the probability of drawing a red ball on the $k^{th}$ draw is $\frac{a}{a+b}$.
As you can see, this expression is a direct representation of the problem, where the $k$ values of $i$ represent the outcome of a particular draw. I derived this expression by enumerating all $2^k$ possibilities and summing their probabilities.
I have already verified the expression for $k=2$ and $k=3$, so I believe the expression should be correct.
Further explanation of the expression:
This summation might seem a bit messy, so I think it's necessary to explain the role of each part.
The outermost summation represents the probability of drawing a red ball on the $k^{th}$ draw under $2^k$ different scenarios (as there are two possibilities for each draw). Here, $i$ represents the outcome of each draw, with $i=0$ indicating a red ball and $i=1$ indicating a white ball.
The product part represents the probability of each draw.
The term $i_j + (-1)^{i_j}$ is used to control the probability of the complementary event.
The denominator of the fraction is the total number of balls after the $k^{th}$ draw, and the numerator is the total number of red balls at this time (as you can see, the sum of $i$ subtracted represents the number of times a white ball is drawn).

@Masd Thank you for your advice. I apologize if my initial post which is lacking in detail. Although I'm still somewhat at a loss with this problem(so what I've done may be not valuable), I have now added more details
